# Is it possible to calculate covariance of two normal distributions?

Tags: statistics, covariance

Given the mean and standard deviation of the normally distributed changes in two measurements from before and after treatment from the same population, is it possible to estimate the covariance of the two samples?

Assume there two things that are measured from a given population before and after some treatment.

However, instead of having the measurements of each individual in the population, we have the distributions of the changes from before and after treatment.

So the differences before and after would be:

$$\delta X = X_{end} - X_{beg} \\$$
$$\delta Y = Y_{end} - Y_{beg} \\$$

The data available, however, are the parameters of the distributions of the changes, $X_{\delta}$ & $Y_{\delta}$, i.e. $mean(\delta X), std(\delta X)$ & $mean(\delta Y), std(\delta Y)$

Where:

$$X_{\delta} \sim \mathcal{N}(mean(\delta X), std(\delta X)) \\$$
$$Y_{\delta} \sim \mathcal{N}(mean(\delta Y), std(\delta Y)) \\$$

In other words, given only the parameters of the distributions of the changes in the the samples, and not the actual individual samples, is there some way to estimate the covariance?

Answer (score 1):

No.  Estimation of covariance requires some information about how the two groups vary together.  In your case, the "before" and "after" measurements constitute the two groups, but without knowing how the "before" and "after" measurements are paired up for each individual, it is not possible to determine covariance.

Comment: Thanks. Couldn't it be possible to estimate within certain bounds of uncertainty? If we know that the population as a whole moved from X_beg -> X_end & Y_beg -> Y_end, then we can estimate the probability of a given individual's starting and ending values. It seems that we could use this to simulate a dataset from which we could estimate the covariance. Obviously within wide bands of uncertainty. Still though, given a strong enough delta for each variable some estimate of the covariance should show via simulation.

Comment: @Jed The answer is still no.  If the data were $$(X,Y) = \{(1,1), (2,2), (3,3), (4,4)\}$$ then the sample covariance is $5/3$, but if it were $$(X,Y) = \{(1,4),(2,3),(3,2),(4,1)\}$$ then the sample covariance is $-5/3$.  As I have already stated, estimation in **any** way is impossible without knowing the pairing of observations between groups.

Comment: thanks again. what about an upper bound using the [cauchy-schwarz inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%E2%80%93Schwarz_inequality)?

Comment: I don't mean to troll. I just have a hard time accepting that there's absolutely nothing we can say about the covariance of these two variables.

Comment: Cauchy-Schwarz gives us bounds on the absolute value of the covariance, namely $(\operatorname{Cov}[X,Y])^2 \le \operatorname{Var}[X]\operatorname{Var}[Y]$, but because it does not give you the sign, this means the covariance can range from the negative extreme to the positive as I illustrated in my earlier example.